# Trying to insert a multi-page HTML element using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a site that needs to use several repeating elements in the left side column. I know if can be housed in an external JS page and embedded into the div on the page.

I would like to be able to update a single page to have it generate the content on the rest of the site.

Here is my code. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<div id="feature_app"> 
<span class="left_col_H1">Featured App</span>
<img src="images/app_icon.png" width="100" height="101" class="feature_app_icon" />
<h1 class="feature_app_name">All Dice</span></h1>
<p class="feature_app_price">Price: $0.99 | <a href="#">Avaliable on iTunes</a></span>
<p class="feature_app_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte adipiscing elit. Proin porttitor feugiat condimentum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with looping the data? Just use a for-, while- or foreach-loop. Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a bespoke service where you tell the community what you want and we develop code for you. Demonstrate that you have at least made an effort by showing the javascript code you've written so far and we'll help you sort out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to load content dynamically. To answer your question, use the following. However, you could also flip your solution so that you load the common menu items from each unique html page (e.g. somepage1.html, somepage1.html). The same technique applies, only instead of loading "somepage.html", you would load "menu.html" from those pages. menu.html would contain the common menu items you posted . Your choice.

demo fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wGArU/

html (add this on your page)

```
<div id="#page-content"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$().ready(function() {

    $('#page-content').load('somepage.html', function() {
        // update somepage.html, and the contents will be loaded into the #page-content divs 
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have seen this done before but I didn't have access to the code to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best bet will be to look into a server-side scripting language such as [PHP](http://www.php.net) or [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/get-started).  If you were to use PHP, for example (the simpler of the two examples I provided), you can simply put your repeating links in a separate file and then use an `include()` statement to insert them in your site.  Then in the future you can just update the one file and it will automatically propagate throughout your site.